# Is it a memory leak if the garbage collector runs abnormally?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I have developed a J2ME web browser application, it is working fine.  I am testing its memory consumption. It seems to me that it has a memory leak, because the green curve that represents the consumed memory of the memory monitor (of the wireless toolkit) reaches the maximum allocated memory (which is 687768 bytes) every 7 requests done by the browser, (i.e. when the end user navigates in the web browser from one page to other for 7 pages) after that the garbage collector runs and frees the allocated memory.

My question is:

- is it a memory leak when the garbage collector runs automatically every 7 page navigation?
- Do I need to run the garbage collector (System.gc()) manually one time per request to prevent the maximum allocated memory to be reached?

Please guide me, thanks

Comment: If it was a memory leak the garbage collector wouldn't free the allocated memory would it?

Comment: If you know the list of objects needed and wouldn't like to generate too much garbage, you can pool these objects and reuse them. This will reduce the frequency of GC runs.

Answer (score 3):

To determine if it is a memory leak, you would need to observe it more.

From your description, i.e. that once the maximum memory is reached, the GC kicks in and is able to free memory for your application to run, it does not sound like there is a leak.

Also you should not call GC yourself since

1. it is only an indication
2. could potentially affect the underlying algorithm affecting its performance.

You should instead focus on why your application needs so much memory in such a short period.

Comment: Thank you Cratylus, Actually the application do a number of cryptography operations per request, these operations worth to consume this amount of memory, however, how can I release the allocated memory since I need a fixed size of memory for a particular classes each time I navigate to a page. i.e. I run the same algorithm per request.

Comment: Either you need need to increase your heap, or make your algorithm more space-efficient if possible.

Comment: @mdawaina -- You don't/can't "deallocate" storage in Java -- storage is reclaimed by GC when there are no longer any references to it.  But storage is only reclaimed during the GC cycle.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is: is it a memory leak when the garbage collector runs automatically every 7 page navigation?

Not necessarily.  It could also be that:

- your heap is too small for the size of problem you are trying to solve, or
- your application is generating (collectable) garbage at a high rate.

In fact, given the numbers you have presented, I'm inclined to think that this is primarily a heap size issue.  If the interval between GC runs decreased over time, then THAT would be evidence that pointed to a memory leak, but if the rate stays steady on average, then it would suggest that the rate of memory usage and reclamation are in balance; i.e. no leak.

> Do I need to run the garbage collector (System.gc()) manually one time per request to prevent the maximum allocated memory to be reached?

No. No. No.

Calling `System.gc()` won't cure a memory leak.  If it is a real memory leak, then calling `System.gc()` will not reclaim the leaked memory.  In fact, all you will do is make your application RUN A LOT SLOWER ... assuming that the JVM doesn't ignore the call entirely.

---

Direct and indirect evidence that the **default** behaviour of HotSpot JVMs is to honour System.gc() calls:

- "For example, the default setting for the DisableExplicitGC option causes JVM to honor Explicit garbage collection requests." - http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/rprf_hotspot_parms.html
- "When JMX is enabled in this way, some JVMs (such as Sun's) that do distributed garbage collection will periodically invoke System.gc, causing a Full GC." - http://static.springsource.com/projects/tc-server/2.0/getting-started/html/ch11s07.html
- "It is best to disable explicit GC by using the flag -XX:+DisableExplicitGC." - http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19396-01/819-0084/pt_tuningjava.html

And from the Java 7 source code:

./openjdk/hotspot/src/share/vm/runtime/globals.hpp

```
  product(bool, DisableExplicitGC, false,                                   \
          "Tells whether calling System.gc() does a full GC")               \
```

where the `false` is the default value for the option.  (And note that this is in the OS / M/C independent part of the code tree.)

Comment: Thanks Stephen for your valuable answer, I think the heap is to small as you said

Comment: Actually System.GC is disabled on most platforms, and is just "suggestive" on the rest.

Comment: @HotLicks - actually 1) "most platforms" is an exaggeration, 2) it is documented as suggestive on ALL platforms, and 3) I already mentioned that the JVM might ignore the call: reread the last 9 words of my answer.

Comment: The point is, System.GC will probably not make your app "run a lot slower" since it basically does nothing at all.  (And "most systems" isn't an exaggeration.)

Comment: @HotLicks - do you have some evidence for your assertion that most JVMs have System.GC disabled?  I've added evidence (including JVM source code) that says that they don't disable it by default.  (I'll grant you that production Java installations *can and should* disable it ...  but that is a different issue.)

Comment: Well, I've worked inside a couple of JVMs myself.  But it's been several versions back.  Dunno when they added the GC option you mention -- I don't recall it.

Comment: Well my memory (based on using an Sun JVMs going back to Java 1.1) is that the default state has always been that running `System.gc()` did something.  According to the online sources I spotted, the  DisableExplicitGC option was present in Java 1.4.2, and there are hints it was in Java 1.2

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a library that makes a good effort to force the GC. As mentioned before, `System.gc()` is asynchronous and won't do anything by itself. You may want to use this library to profile your application and find the spots where too much garbage is being produced. You can read more about it in [this article](http://mentablog.soliveirajr.com/2012/11/real-time-java-programming-without-gc/) where I describe the GC problem in detail.

Answer (score 0):

That is (semi) normal behavior.  Available (unreferenced) storage is not collected until the size of the heap reaches some threshold, triggering a collection cycle.

You can reduce the frequency of GC cycles by being a bit more "heap aware".  Eg, a common error in many programs is to parse a string by using substring to not only parse off the left-most word, but also shorten the remaining string by substringing to the right.  Creating a new String for the word is not easily avoided, but one can easily avoid repeatedly substringing the "tail" of the original string.

Running System.GC will accomplish nothing -- on most platforms it's a no-op, since it's so commonly abused.

Note that (outside of brain-dead Android) you can't have a true "memory leak" in Java (unless there's a serious JVM bug).  What's commonly referred to as a "leak" in Java is the failure to remove all references to objects that will never be used again.  Eg, you might keep putting data into a chain and never clear pointers to the stuff on the far end of the chain that is no longer going to be used.  The resulting symptom is that the MINIMUM heap used (ie, the size immediately after GC runs) keeps rising each cycle.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the other excellent answers:

Looks like you are confusing *memory leak* with *garbage collection*.

*Memory leak* is when unused memory cannot be garbage collected because it still has references somewhere (although they're not used for anything).

*Garbage collection* is when a piece of software (the garbage collector) frees unreferenced memory automatically.

You should not call the garbage collector manually because that would affect its performance.